# How do I generate weight variable in STATA

Tags: stata

I am working on a question that asks me to solve for the weighted average of my dependent variable (hourly wage) by using the weight of my independent variable (which is a discrete variable that has 16 categories and more than 300,000 observations). as you can see below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBGLx.png)

how am I suppose to generate the weighted variable for a variable that has so many observations?

Comment: posting a question here doesn't count as working on it

Answer (score 2):

First you should determine whether the weights of **x** are sampling weights, frequency weights or analytic weights. Then, if **y** is your dependent variable and **x_weights** is the variable that contains the weights for your independent variable, type in:

`mean y [pweight = x_weight]` for sampling (probability) weights

`mean y [fweight = x_weight]` for frequency weights

`mean y [aweight = x_weight]` for analytic weights

You can find a nice summary of these different options [here](http://www.cpc.unc.edu/research/tools/data_analysis/statatutorial/sample_surveys/weight_syntax), as well as information on the more specialized option `iweight`.